# Is $\frac{∂}{x_{j}} \phi(\vec{r})$ at $\vec{ r}=0$ the same as $\frac{∂}{∂x_{j}} \phi(0)$ cause this is what the author stated in the attached screen?

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

[image]

In the attached picture, the author evaluated first $ \frac{∂}{∂x_{j}} \phi(\vec{r})$ then to evaluate, in the line below it, $\frac{∂}{∂x_{j}} \phi(0)$, he simply substituted $\vec{r}=0$ in the calculation above it, so can that be done? another question is had we started with equation (1.29) shouldn't $\frac{∂}{∂x_{j}} \phi(0)$ be zero to begin with?

Comment: Is your concern that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(\varphi(0)) = 0$ or is it that $x_j$ doesn't explicitly appear in the definition of $\varphi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What $\mathbf{r} = 0$ means in this context $\mathbf{r} = (0,\dots 0)$
so with that in mind
$$
\vert\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r_0}\vert = \vert- \mathbf{r_0}\vert = r_0
$$

This is evaluating the potential at a single point, so is a constant as it is now independent of $\mathbf{r}$, so the potential derivative would indeed be $0$ evaluated at $\mathbf{r} = 0$. Sidenote, the derivative would be $0$ at any specific point e.g. $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r_{1}}$

To answer your follow up question - it appears the derivation is really computing
$$
\frac{\partial \phi(\mathbf{r})}{\partial x_j}(\mathbf{r} = 0) = \frac{\partial \phi(\mathbf{r})}{\partial x_j}\big\vert_{\mathbf{r} =0} = -\frac{\alpha}{r_0^2}\frac{-x_{j0}}{r_0} = \frac{\alpha}{r_0^3}x_{j0}
$$